# OpenCV: Processing camera input as fast and prompt as possible. Flush read buffer to skip old frames

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer, video-capture, flush

Using an instance of `cv::VideoCapture` one can read frames form a camera. If these frames shall be processed (e.g. to detect qr-code or any other feature) and the processing takes longer than the frame period of the camera, there will be frames buffered. Thus if one frame is done the next one shall be read. But for being as responsive as possible the latest frame available and not an old buffered one shall be processed next.

**How do I get the most recent frame out of `cv::VideoCapture`?**

It is possible to skip frames by using `grab()` (see [answers.opencv](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24714)). But there seems to be no way to find out if we reached the most recent frame. No count of buffered frames, no *"grabed the last"* indication, no *"flush read buffer"*.

The only advice I became asking this at [answers.opencv](http://answers.opencv.org/question/81702) was to use multi threading to read the buffer as fast as possible and handover the latest frame to the working thread. These are things embedded developers are getting stomach ache of. Using multi threading to flush a buffer, is like ... *(I don't need to explain)*.

Is there really no way to process camera images just as fast as the CPU is able to do?

Just a little code:

```
for ( ;; ) {
  vcap.grab();
  vcap.retrieve( frame );
  usleep( 990000UL );                  // wait 990ms for nothing
  cv::imshow( windowName, frame );
  if ( cv::waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 ) break; // wait 10ms for keypress
}
```

This will show the frames several (not one) seconds delayed (using `read()` or `>>` is the same).

Comment: i think if you grab from webcam you will grab most recent frame. you will lose frames you missed if processing takes longer than the frame period. when you grab from video you will grab all frames.

Comment: As far as I know `grab()` and `retrieve()` (decode) are just the two components of `read()`: "Grabs, decodes and returns the *next* video frame.". A sequence of 'grab()' and 'retrieve()' is equal to a single call of `read()`.